# How to use style on input field in Demandware?

Tags: templates, demandware

**I want to append an image in input field in Demandware...**

I am wondering to use style on Demandware's isinputfield tag, can i acheive this in Demandware Templates like on this tag

```
isinputfield formfield="${pdict.CurrentForms.helloform.nickname}" type="input"
```

Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

`isinputfield` is a custom *ISML* tag, implemented in template

> {cartridge_name}/cartridge/templates/default/util/inputfield.isml

You can use the parameter `rowClass` to specify a CSS class for the surrounding div (you can actually see the code that uses this parameter in the template mentioned above)

e.g.

```
<isinputfield
    formfield="${pdict.CurrentForms.giftcert.purchase.from}"
    rowClass="label-above"
    type="input" />
```

After that you would need to provide a CSS styling for the class you have applied.